# Breeze with stored procedure CLR error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

Im trying to call a stored procedure using Entity framework.
If I go direcly to the web api method it works fine, but when calling it from breeze it causes an exception on the metadata method.
The error is :
"Could not find the CLR type for...".
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Need to see some code showing what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue, but thank God I figured out a solution. Instead of using a stored procedure, you should use a view, as Breeze recognizes views as `DbSet<T>`, just like tables. Say you have a SQL server table that contains two tables Customers and Orders.

```
Customers (**CustomerId**, FirstName, LastName)
Orders (OrderId, #CustomerId, OrderDate, OrderTotal)
```

Now, say you want a query that returns orders by CustomerId. Usually, you would do that in a stored procedure, but as I said, you need to use a view instead. So the query will look like this in the view.

```
Select o.OrderId, c.CustomerId, o.OrderDate, o.OrderTotal
from dbo.Orders o inner join dbo.Customers c on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
```

Notice there is no filtering (where ...). So:

i. Create a [general] view that includes the filtering key(s) and name it, say, `OrdersByCustomers`

ii. Add the OrdersByCustomers view to the entity model in your VS project

iii. Add the entity to the Breeze controller, as such:

```
public IQueryable<OrdersByCustomers> OrdersByCustomerId(int id)  
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.OrdersByCustomers
                                   .Where(r => r.CustomerId == id);
}
```

Notice the **.Where(r => r.CustomerId == id)** filter. We could do it in the data service file, but because we want the user to see only his personal data, we need to filter from the server so it only returns his data.

iv. Now, that the entity is set in the controller, you may invoke it in the data service file, as such:

```
var getOrdersByCustomerId = function(orderObservable, id)
{
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('OrdersByCustomerId')
                                  .WithParameters({ CustomerId: id });

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
                  .then(function(data) {
                      if (orderObservable) orderObservable(data.results);
                  }
                  .fail(function(e) {
                      logError('Retrieve Data Failed');
                  }
}
```

v. You probably know what to do next from here.

Hope it helps.